# Question about lightning icon and button

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, html

I'm trying to create a button in a lightning component, the purpose of this button is to delete a record (in a list of records).

So for now the easiest way to do that is like that :

```
<button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.deleteContact}" data-data="{!contact.Id}">delete</button>
```

because in this kind of button I can put the attibute `data` that help me to get the id of the record in the javascript, so I can delete the record selected.

But I'd like to replace the word `delete` in the button with an icon like that :

```
<button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.deleteContact}" data-data="{!contact.Id}">
    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:delete" size="small" class="icon" />
</button>
```

But then when I try to click the delete button I got an error :

> [event.target.getAttribute is not a function]

But I only try to add an icon, for me the way the button works is not changed ?

Here is the javascript function in case there is something wrong in it, but that method work when there is no icon in the button (the record is corectly deleted) :

```
deleteContact : function (component, event, helper) { 
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-data") || event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-data")
    var action = component.get("c.deleteCon");
    action.setParams({
        "idContact": id
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        component.set("v.contacts", actionResult.getReturnValue());  
        helper.getContacts(component);          
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by adding an icon in the  button, the element that is the origin of the event is now the icon. The `target` property of the `event` is linked to the originator of the event.

To resolve this, you can use the `event.currentTarget` property instead of `event.target`. The `currentTarget` property will linked to the element attached to the event listener (i.e. your button).

Comment: Thank you it works ! So it means that if I had put the word 'delete' into a div or a span tag for example, I would have used `event.currentTarget` too ?

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad I could help. If you put an html element inside the button, yes you'll have to use the `event.currentTarget` property too.